# Applying hidden Markov model to multiple simultaneous bit sequences

Tags: c#, machine-learning, hidden, markov-models

This [excellent article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/69647/Hidden-Markov-Models-in-Csharp.aspx) on implementing a Hidden Markov Model in C# does a fair job of classifying a single bit sequence based on training data.

How to modify the algorithm, or build it out (multiple HMMs?) to support the classification of multiple simultaneous bit sequences?

### Example

Instead of classifying just one stream:

```
double t1 = hmm.Evaluate(new int[] { 0,1 });      // 0.49999423004045024  
double t2 = hmm.Evaluate(new int[] { 0,1,1,1 });  // 0.11458685045803882
```

Rather classify a dual bit stream:

```
double t1 = hmm.Evaluate(new int[] { [0, 0], [0, 1] });
double t2 = hmm.Evaluate(new int[] { [0, 0], [1, 1], [0, 1], [1, 1] });
```

Or even better, three streams:

```
double t1 = hmm.Evaluate(new int[] { [0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1] });
double t2 = hmm.Evaluate(new int[] { [0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1] });
```

Obviously the training data would also be expanded.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to model the set of observations as the n-ary cartesian product of all possible values of each sequence, in your case the HMM will have `2^n` output symbol where `n` is the number of bit sequences.

Example: for three bit sequences, the 8 symbols are: `000 001 010 011 100 101 110 111`, as if we created a *megavariable* whose values are all the possible tuples of values of the individual observation sequences (`0/1` of each bit sequence)

Comment: I thought of that, but it intuitively feels like we are throwing information away. Given 3 bit streams (A, B & C) representing sensor data, if sequence A and B are correlated in that sequence B tends to go high shortly after A then any noise introduced by C would hide this correlation, eg. [A,B,C]: [0,0,x], [1,0,x], [1,1,x] where x could be any value of C and any training data would have to account for every possibility of C during those 3 states.

Comment: @FreshCode: I might have used the wrong words, I was talking about observation symbols (emissions) not states (the hidden states). Also keep in mind that in HMM, the emission model only depends on the current state `$P( O_t | q_0,..,q_t , O_0,...,O_{t-1} ) = P( O_t | q_t )$` (what is known as the Markov assumption of evidence)

Comment: I guess the alternative is to adapt the emission matrix to have some kind of multivariate version of the multinomial distribution, as well as making the corresponding changes to the Baum-Welch training algorithm...

Answer (score 1):

The article mentioned deals with the hidden Markov model implementation in the [Accord.NET Framework](https://code.google.com/p/accord/). When using the complete version of the framework, and not just the subproject available in that article, one can use the generic [HiddenMarkovModel](http://accord.googlecode.com/svn/docs/html/T_Accord_Statistics_Models_Markov_HiddenMarkovModel_1.htm) model and use any suitable emission symbol distribution. If the user would like to express the joint probability between two or three discrete variables, it would be worth to use the [JointDistribution](http://accord.googlecode.com/svn/docs/html/T_Accord_Statistics_Distributions_Multivariate_JointDistribution.htm) class.

If, however, there are many symbol variables, such that expression all possible variable combinations is not practical, it should be better to use a continuous representation for the features and use a [Multivariate Normal distribution](http://accord.googlecode.com/svn/docs/html/T_Accord_Statistics_Distributions_Multivariate_MultivariateNormalDistribution.htm) instead.

An example would be:

```
// Specify a initial normal distribution for the samples.
var initialDensity = MultivariateNormalDistribution(3); // 3 dimensions

// Create a continuous hidden Markov Model with two states organized in a forward
//  topology and an underlying multivariate Normal distribution as probability density.
var model = new HiddenMarkovModel<MultivariateNormalDistribution>(new Ergodic(2), density);

// Configure the learning algorithms to train the sequence classifier until the
// difference in the average log-likelihood changes only by as little as 0.0001
var teacher = new BaumWelchLearning<MultivariateNormalDistribution>(model)
{
    Tolerance = 0.0001,
    Iterations = 0,
};

// Fit the model
double likelihood = teacher.Run(sequences);
```